# How to force fully close tor browser

Tags: process, tor, kill

I am trying to close the Tor browser by killing the process using this command:

```
sudo kill pid
```

However, the Tor browser is not closing and it shows this pop up (see screenshot) with the following message:

> Restarting Tor will not close your browser tabs

[image: Tor browser pop up]

Here is a screenshot of the `top` command:

[image: top command output]

I want to close the Tor browser when I am killing the process. What should I do?

Comment: This seems like a misuse of both `sudo` and `kill` commands. Why not just close it with the Close button?

Comment: Well my requirement is not to close it by GUI.

Answer (score 0):

First off, closing any application by killing its process(es) is dangerous, and certainly atypical.

That said, it sounds like you're not finding the proper PID(s) for the process(es) you're hoping to kill.

The command `ps -ef | grep <process-name>` will enumerate all processes running with name `<process-name>`.

I'd guess that "tor" might be the process-name in question. But, to figure *that* out, you can run the command `top` to see what's currently running, and infer from there.

Comment: Still the pop up is coming when I am trying to kill the process. Take a look I have uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: What does `top` show? It still sounds like there are related processes that are running...

Comment: I have added the screenshot of top, please take a look. I am killing the tor process shown in screenshot still tor is not closing and showing the pop up like 2nd screenshot.

Comment: To make sure you're killing all related processes, you can use the `pkill` command (derivative of the `pgrep` command mentioned), which basically kills all processes based on name (more here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill). Again, beware of how you use this command, as it's quite powerful.

Comment: "pkill" is also not able to close tor still pop up is coming. It looks like tor can not be closed from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
pgrep applicationName
```

will show you the list of all associated processes. From there you can choose which process id you should kill.

Answer (score 0):

First, define

```
function abortFirstMatch () {
  searchString=$1
  foundPid=$(ps -ef | grep ${searchString} | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}')
  kill -9 ${foundPid}
}
```

then use it

```
abortFirstMatch "tor browser"
```